# Calendar returning the wrong time

Tags: java, calendar

The time displayed is way ahead of what I expected. I'm parsing a date string and turning it into milliseconds.

```
year = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(1));
mo = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2));
day = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(3));
hr = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(4));
min = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(5));
sec = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(6));
```

and here I set the Calendar

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, mo, day, hr, min, sec);
time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "way ahead of what it should be"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the calendar documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), then visit [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY), you'll see that January is month 0. You'll want to change your code to `mo = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2))-1;`

Comment: this is more of an assumption than an answer.

Comment: @user798759, be more specific next time...you were fortunate this time.

Comment: @mre I figured if they are "parsing a date string" it would be human readable, which means the month would be one greater than it should be. that also explains why the time is way ahead

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use DateFormatter to parse the date string (rather than rolling your own).

Other than that, make sure that you have the proper time zone and understand that month number one is February (not January).

Comment: I'd wager a beer on it being the always fun zero-indexed month.